# Docker image ubuntu:21.10 produces The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.10

I am creating a docker image FROM ubuntu:21.10

All worked fine a couple of weeks ago but today I get:

```
Step 3/76 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
 ---> Running in 7f2afb2074e8
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I have been looking around to fix it but I really don't know how.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your dockerfile try using ubuntu:jammy, that worked fine for me.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and on it i am using the container datadog-agent, now I am not able to use this command apt-get update && apt-get install nano, 
getting above error.